# Find the real eigenvalues if any

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the 2nd order boundary value problem

$ x^2 y''- \lambda xy'+ \lambda y=0 \ ,$

subject to

$ y(1)=0 \ \ and \ \ y(3)=y'(3) \ .$

**Find the real eigenvalues if any.**

**Answer** :

My approach is as follows:

Let $ \ \ x=e^z \ ,$  then $ \ z=\log (x) \ .$

Now $ \ \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1}{x} \frac{dy}{dz} \ \ and \ \ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{1}{x^2} \frac{d^2y}{dz^2}-\frac{1}{x^2} \frac{dy}{dz}  $.

Thus, the equation becomes

$ \frac{d^2y}{dz^2}-(1+\lambda ) \frac{dy}{dz} +\lambda y=0 \ .$

**But now I can't proceed to find the eigenvalues.**

**Please, help me out.**

Comment: What is the characteristic polynomial of your transformed equation? What do the roots look like?

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equation can be factored as

$$ r^2 - (1+ \lambda)r + \lambda = (r-1)(r-\lambda) $$

If $\lambda = 1$, there's a double root and the solution takes the form

$$ y = Ae^z + Bze^z = Ax + Bx\ln x  $$

Otherwise, there are two distinct roots

$$ y = Ae^z + Be^{\lambda z} = Ax + Bx^{\lambda} $$

It's up to you to determine $\lambda$ values that satisfy the boundary conditions